# Firebase error 403. Your client does not have permission to access this url

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Dears

I'm having issue with my firebase lately. My app uses firebase authentication. Sometimes it works fine, but some times when I try to get OTP, I get error. After that even if I try to access firebase website from same device browser, I get the error 403. Your client does not have permission to access this URL. Means I cannot access firebase from that device at all.

Note that I'm in a country where we have restricted internet access and I have to use VPN to access many sites, including firebase. After few trials, when I change VPN servers, I can again access firebase in my browser, but as soon as I try using my app, it blocks again.

I have seached a lot on this issue, but couldn't find any solution. Most of the solutions are related to firebase cloud access, but in my case I cannot access firebase at all.

Please also note that I have tried using simulators as well as tried using my mobile for testing.

If you need any further details on the issue, please let me know.

PS: I'm a flutter developer and authentication is working fine if firebase access is not blocked.

Comment: That sounds frustrating. I am not sure the issue has anything to do with Firebase though - it sounds like ip addresses or ports are being blocked by something sitting between you and Firebase. Possibly you're using too much bandwidth and the VPN is throttling the connection or maybe even blocking it - which would explain why changing to another VPN corrects the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried two different VPN services, both have same issue unfortunately

Comment: Understood and sorry for that issue. SO is not the proper forum for assistance with networking issues as there is nothing we can do to resolve them - SO is a coding specific forum. See [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I think your best bet it so contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as they will have more information related to access from different countries.